# Get exact reuest header in node http

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Is there a way to see/inspect the complete request header send by the native node `http` module? I'm doing sth. like that:

```
const req = Http.request(http_request_options, res => {...
```

and I' like to see if there are any cookies send with this request.

Comment: no http client in node send cookie if u don't explicitly pass it imo. even then i think u have to use withCredential:true option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Node's [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) will tell you of any headers it will add. Reviewing it, it looks like by default it will add the `Host` header, but I didn't see any others unless you add `auth` in the options. (And a quick test using the methods below confirmed that.)

Also, `request` returns a [`ClientRequest` object](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest), which has methods you can use to inspect it, such as [`getRawHeaderNames`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_getrawheadernames) (new in v15.13) and [`getHeader`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_getheader_name), which you could use to see what headers are present.

Externally, you could always set up a quick HTTP server (perhaps also using Node) to see what headers you receive...